# add more than 30 days with Calendar's add() method in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I'm not quite sure what field to use when adding more than 30 days to a Java Calendar object. Is there any difference in between `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` and `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR`?

Example:

```
GregorianCalendar d = new GregorianCalendar();
d.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 90);
```

vs

```
GregorianCalendar d = new GregorianCalendar();
d.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 90);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You code implies that all months have 30 days.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think it makes a difference when you call add. The distinction is important when you call the getters.

Both methods work fine, right? For more than 30 days, as well as negative amounts.

The (admittedly complicated) source for GregorianCalendar#add has this section:

```
 case DAY_OF_MONTH: // synonym of DATE
 case DAY_OF_YEAR:
 case DAY_OF_WEEK:
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks for the source confirmation.

Comment: The behaviour of over-/underflow when using the add method is well defined in the API documentation: "Overflow occurs when a field value exceeds its range and, as a result, the next larger field is incremented or decremented and the field value is adjusted back into its range." So overflowing the DAY_OF_MONTH field, means that the MONTH field (next larger) is incremented and the DAY_OF_MONTH field set to 1 (adjusted back into its valid range).

Comment: @jarnbjo: and I think the exact same thing happens for DAY_OF_YEAR, DAY_OF_WEEK and DATE.

Comment: @Thilo Is it the same for WEEK_OF_YEAR && WEEK_OF_MONTH in calender.add()??  Ans:
Yes, It looks like same in source code "case WEEK_OF_YEAR: == case WEEK_OF_MONTH: == case DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH:"

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
         .plusDays( 30 )
```

## Details

Much easier now with the modern java.time classes that supplant the old `Calendar` & `Date` classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

You can add a number of days to that.

```
LocalDate later = today.plusDays( 30 );
```

## `Period`

You can represent a span of time with the `Period` class.

```
Period thirtyDays = Period.ofDays( 30 );
```

You can perform date math by calling `plus` or `minus` methods.

```
LocalDate later = today.plus( thirtyDays );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).