# Subtracting days in a Calendar object

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyone know a simple way using java calendar to subtract X days to a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212321/anyone-know-a-simple-way-using-java-calendar-to-subtract-x-days-to-a-date)

I need to minus 365 days in a given date (givenDate)-

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(givenDate);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -365);
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 13):

`Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR` is the proper way to subtract days

You can also subtract a year (taking in to account leap years) by using

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(givenDate);
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
```

Comment: Actually calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, n) and calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, n) are identical. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506082/add-more-than-30-days-with-calendars-add-method-in-java/2506096#2506096

Answer (score 4):

That is the correct way to subtract days.

Note that 365 days does not always equal one year because of leap days. `calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1)` would subtract one year correctly.

You also may want to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net)-library instead of `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`. Joda Time is a much nicer API for handling times and dates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it'll make a different, but I would use [**Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_YEAR) as the field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to ***strictly*** subtract 365 days, then yeah, that'd do it. However, if you are trying years backward, that might not work due to leap years.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Veyder-time](http://veyder-time.enblom.org). It is a simple and powerful alternativ to java.util.Calendar and has simple methods for adding and subtracting both days and years, among many other things.