# How to subtract X day from a Date object in Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, java.util.date

I want to do something like:

```
Date date = new Date(); // current date
date = date - 300; // substract 300 days from current date and I want to use this "date"
```

How to do it?

Comment: Obligatory "Use Joda Time" remark.

Comment: The following links might be useful for you.[enter link description here][1]


[enter link description here][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212321/anyone-know-a-simple-way-using-java-calendar-to-subtract-x-days-to-a-date
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623610/subtracting-days-in-a-calendar-object

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 396, accepted):

## Java 8 and later

With Java 8's date time API change, Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().minusDays(300);
```

Similarly you can have

```
LocalDate date = someLocalDateInstance.minusDays(300);
```

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885950/260990 for translation between java.util.Date <--> java.time.LocalDateTime

```
Date in = new Date();
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(in.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
Date out = Date.from(ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

## Java 7 and earlier

Use [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)'s [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) method

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateInstance);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
Date dateBefore30Days = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: It is to set your custom dateInstance in case you don't want to consider current date time

Comment: Java's Date handling is *so* bloated!

Comment: This is 4 year old answer. there have been new DateTime API changes made to recent versions of it. I will edit the answer

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @JigarJoshi it would be terrific if you updated your answer with the Java 8 API. Your answer is the accepted one that people see first.

Comment: Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: kind of the wrong answer because you're assuming *now* instead of an arbitrary date object

Comment: @bharal ofcourse you can have instance of LocalDateTime instead.

Comment: @JigarJoshi i suppose what i'm saying is you need to start with some arbitrary date object, convert it to the localDate, minus, and unconvert, to fully answer the question

Answer (score 73):

@JigarJoshi it's the good answer, and of course also @Tim recommendation to use .[joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

I only want to add more possibilities to subtract days from a `java.util.Date`.

#### Apache-commons

One possibility is to use [apache-commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/). You can do it using [`DateUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) as follows:

```
Date dateBefore30Days = DateUtils.addDays(new Date(),-30);
```

Of course add the `commons-lang` dependency to do only date subtract it's probably not a good options, however if you're already using `commons-lang` it's a good choice. There is also convenient methods to `addYears`,`addMonths`,`addWeeks` and so on, take a look at the [api here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html).

#### Java 8

Another possibility is to take advantage of new [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) from *Java 8* using [`minusDays(long days)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#minusDays-long-) method:

```
LocalDate dateBefore30Days = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).minusDays(30);
```

Comment: No point to using `LocalDateTime` as that class purposely has no concept of time zone nor offset-from-UTC. Use that only when zone/offset is unknown or not relevant. Instead use `LocalDate` and pass a `ZoneId` when calling its `now` method. See the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37658868/642706) by Jacob van Lingen.

Comment: @BasilBourque After your advise, I check the api and you're totally right, therefore I update the answer. thanks.

Comment: [Brian Montellano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10106761/brian-montellano) would like to comment: there shouldn’t be any `s` in `DateUtils`, it’s just `DateUtil`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Brian Montellano is wrong, you can check the [`DateUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) docs

Answer (score 43):

Simply use this to get date before 300 days, replace 300 with your days:

```
Date date = new Date(); // Or where ever you get it from
Date daysAgo = new DateTime(date).minusDays(300).toDate();
```

Here,

`DateTime` is `org.joda.time.DateTime;`

`Date` is `java.util.Date`

Comment: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), and advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 37):

Java 8 Time API:

```
Instant now = Instant.now(); //current date
Instant before = now.minus(Duration.ofDays(300));
Date dateBefore = Date.from(before);
```

Comment: I must mean Java 8 API, not 7. And mentioning the package `java.time` might help. Also, some discussion/explanation is generally expected on Stack Overflow rather than just a code snippet. You should definitely explain `Duration` as that is the added-value of your Answer over [the existing one by van Lingen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37658868/642706).

Comment: Java 8 of cause, fixed

Comment: so close, but should be for modifying an arbitrary date object, not "now"

Answer (score 12):

As you can see [**HERE**](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-date-time-date-manipulation-java/) there is a lot of manipulation you can do. Here an example showing what you could do!

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

//Add one day to current date.
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

//Substract one day to current date.
cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

/* Can be Calendar.DATE or
*  Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.SECOND
*/
```

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: I didn't see your answer... Should I delete mine?

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 10):

With Java 8 it's really simple now:

```
 LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().minusDays(300);
```

A great guide to the new api can be found [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/03/20-examples-of-date-and-time-api-from-Java8.html).

Comment: I suggest always passing the optional time zone (or offset-from-UTC) to that `now` method. If omitted, the JVM‘s current default time zone is implicitly and silently applied. That default lies outside your control and can change at any moment, even *during* runtime. Example: `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )`.

Comment: needs to be on an arbitrary date object as per the question, not "now"

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8 you can do this:

```
Instant inst = Instant.parse("2018-12-30T19:34:50.63Z"); 

// subtract 10 Days to Instant 
Instant value = inst.minus(Period.ofDays(10)); 
// print result 
System.out.println("Instant after subtracting Days: " + value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a function to make the task easier.

- For 7 days after dateString: `dateCalculate(dateString,"yyyy-MM-dd",7);`
- To get 7 days upto dateString: `dateCalculate(dateString,"yyyy-MM-dd",-7);`

---

```
public static String dateCalculate(String dateString, String dateFormat, int days) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    try {
        cal.setTime(s.parse(dateString));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
    return s.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Comment: This Answer uses troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` that are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: The Question involves date-time objects, not generating strings. By the way, `LocalDate.parse( "2017-01-23").plusWeeks( 1 )` is simpler than writing your own method and is more self-documenting.

Answer (score 1):

You may also be able to use the `Duration` class. E.g.

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date oneDayFromCurrentDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - Duration.ofDays(1).toMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily subtract with calendar with SimpleDateFormat

```
 public static String subtractDate(String time,int subtractDay) throws ParseException {


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(time));
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE,-subtractDay);
        String wantedDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

        Log.d("tag",wantedDate);
        return wantedDate;

    }
```