# Java Date object shows time in the future

Tags: java, date, datetime

I'm making a new date object some time before current time. If I have it to show 1 day before today, it works fine. but if I want to show 30 days ago, it goes to future (?)

```
Date date = new Date();
long sometime = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //a day
System.out.println(date.getTime() );
Date sometimeago = new Date(date.getTime() - sometime);
System.out.println(sometimeago );
sometime = 30* 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //a month
sometimeago = new Date(date.getTime() - sometime);
System.out.println(sometimeago );
```

Output:

```
1408160853776
Thu Aug 14 20:47:33 PDT 2014
Thu Sep 04 13:50:21 PDT 2014
```

What's limiting here?  Reaching Long limit?

Comment: You should look at the `Calendar` class which does much of the calculation for you.

Comment: Or better yet, the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API (if you're using Java 8).  Or if you can't, use JodaTime.  Days aren't always 24 hours.  Months aren't always 30 days.  And the original date/time/calendar classes (and related formatters/parsers) had lots of issues.

Comment: just additional note: read about leap seconds, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 is not always 1 day, use calendar

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

integer overflow in `int` literals,

in your case `int` literals gets evaluted before and that results in negative result and than gets assigned to `long`

```
sometime = 30* 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //a month
```

this results in `-1702967296`

convert it to

```
sometime = 30* 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L; //a month
```

note: `L` to make it `long` literal and then multiply

Better to use `Calendar` class for `Date` manipulation

---

**Also See**

- [How to subtract X day from a Date object  in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882926/how-to-subtract-x-day-from-a-date-object-in-java)

Comment: Shouldn't the `30` be `30L` to force all calculations to be longs?

Comment: @Code if any of those is `long` the expression will get evaluated in `long`

Comment: @JigarJoshi Yes, the final value is a `long`, but there are several intermediate calculations that result in an `int` and leave open the potential for overflow. By changing the first literal to a `long`, all intermediate results will also be `long`, thus avoiding **all** potential overflow errors.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now()
         .minusDays( 1 )
```

## java.time

The modern java.time classes provide these functions.

> If I have it to show 1 day before today,

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
LocalDate yesterday = today.minusDays( 1 ) ;
```

> I want to show 30 days ago

```
LocalDate thirtyDaysAgo = today.minusDays( 30 ) ;
```

Or perhaps you want a logical month rather than literally thirty days.

```
LocalDate monthAgo = today.minusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

Perhaps you want a date-time rather than a date-only value.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtYesterday = now.minusDays( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtThirtyDaysAgo = now.minusDays( 30 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtMonthAgo = now.minusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).