# java.util.Date before() function gives false for dates before 1 month

Tags: java, date

Here is a code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        long oneMonthAgo=30*24*60*60*1000;
        Date now = new Date();
        Date twf=new Date(now.getTime()-oneMonthAgo);
        System.out.println(twf.before(now));
    }
```

This outputs false

While this code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        long twentyDaysAgo=20*24*60*60*1000;
        Date now = new Date();
        Date twf=new Date(now.getTime()-twentyDaysAgo);
        System.out.println(twf.before(now));
    }
```

Output: True

Isnt it strange enough
?

Comment: looks like similar to the question in the below link :-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336770/java-date-object-shows-time-in-the-future

Comment: @ManjunathAnand exactly!! That answers my question.

Comment: Yeps, change to: `long twentyFourHours=30*24*60*60*1000L;`

Comment: @rahulserver Please mark this question as answered (I dont know how to do it) so that it doesnt show up as unanswered

Comment: @ManjunathAnand I dont think it can be marked as answered without an answer. It can be marked as duplicate though. However IMHO in my question I have included SSCE as well. So its better for the forum than the other counterpart.

Comment: @JigarJoshi pls note that the other question's answer has not yet been marked as accepted. So I wonder whether this question should be marked as duplicate.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: Side note: why is the variable called `twentyFourHours`?

Comment: FYI: `LocalDate.now().minusMonths( 1 )`