# How to fetch data's between two dates in android (not sqlite)?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, date

I tried to do to fetch the data's between from and to dates.
I did it on sql lite,it works and 
I tried in android coding part,it doesn't work,could you guys please help

```
protected void adddata1() throws ParseException {

Database db=new Database(Reportmonth.this);
SQLiteDatabase sb=db.getReadableDatabase();


String a=from.getText().toString();
String b=to.getText().toString();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");


 Date a1=sdf.parse(a);//convert string to date
Date b1=sdf.parse(b);//convert string to date


Cursor cus=sb.rawQuery("select * from expenz where daty between '" + a1 +"' AND '"+b1+"'",null);

cus.moveToFirst();
 for(int i=0;i<cus.getCount();i++)
     {


     if(cus!=null) //i think the error starts from this onwards.        
     {                           
         soi.setText(cus.getString(0));


         Log.i("",cus.getString(0));

          desc.setText(cus.getString(3));

          dat.setText(cus.getString(1));

          woc.setText(cus.getString(2));


          amount.setText(cus.getString(5));

          adddata();

          search.setClickable(false);

  }      
     cus.moveToNext();

     } 

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Is it crashing? Is it getting dates in a different range? Is it drawing a picture of a chicken on the screen?

Comment: What is your Date Format in Sqlite Database.

Comment: nothing displayed..Pages shows as blank

Comment: First i tried Date as a date format and now use varchar,

Comment: If you are using `varchar` for storing date, this query will not work. May be you have to get all values and then convert the database values to `Date` and then compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not advisable to store `date` in database as `varchar` as when it comes to situation like yours, its a real pain

Still below I have shown a work around, where you can extract all data from the table, convert the date column in the table from `string` to `Date` object and then do your comparison. But this will **hit the performance** a lot specially when the rows in your database is really high.

```
//For storing the rows that are in between the date range
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> rowList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

//Important that the date should be in the same format as specified above
Date startDate = sdf.parse(a);//convert string to date
Date endDate = sdf.parse(b);//convert string to date

Cursor cus = sb.rawQuery("select * from expenz",null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        try {
            //Converting the database `varchar date` to `Date` object here
            //Here cursor.getString(X) should be the column number of your daty column
            //And also the date format in the database should also be same as "yyyy-MM-dd"
            Date thisDate = sdf.parse(cursor.getString(X));

            // Check if the database date is within the range
            if (thisDate.after(startDate) && thisDate.before(endDate)) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                //Here have the number of columns you want to have according to your database
                map.put("column0", cursor.getString(0));
                map.put("column1", cursor.getString(1));
                map.put("column2", cursor.getString(2));
                map.put("column3", cursor.getString(3));
                map.put("column4", cursor.getString(4));
                map.put("column5", cursor.getString(5));

                rowList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// Now here the rowList will have the rows between the specified date range
```

You could modify the inner most `if loop` to meet your requirements.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks dude..you saved me...I have a doubt if the given date also have the records means how we show in if condition.

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you please explain a little more.

Comment: i gave a start date and end date it displays in between dates data's,if the start and end date also have a record means how to display start and end date date data's also?

Comment: In that case, try subracting one day from start date and adding one day to the end date.

Comment: You can refer this answer to add and subract date http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882926/how-to-subtract-x-day-from-a-date-object-in-java