# how to execute java functions in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to get the date using java namespace in XSLT file, and minus X no of days from it. How to minus days from from date in xslt?

I tried using java namespace to get the current date and use the
java.time.LocalDate.now().minusDays(2) the days.
It works fine in java but in xslt it fails

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                              xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" 
                              xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
                              xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                              xmlns:datetime="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
                              xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
                              xmlns:date="http://www.date.org/"
                              xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
                              xmlns:js="javascript:code"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="java"
                              extension-element-prefixes="mcr">

    <xsl:variable name="test" select="java:java.time.LocalDate.now().minusDays(2)"/>
```

when I am using only "java:java.time.LocalDate.now()" in select, I am getting today's date as output. Only the minusDays() function doesn't seem to work.

I am expecting an output which is currentDate minus 2 days
in yyyy-MM-dd format.
Ex : if today's Date is 12 June, 2019 
OUTPUT : 2019-06-10

Comment: can you try this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882926/how-to-subtract-x-day-from-a-date-object-in-java)

Comment: "it fails" is not a good description of problem. And Java is not part of XSLT. If your processor happens to support it, there may be limits to that support.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid XPath function call: java:java.time.LocalDate.now(), which Xalan interprets as a call on an external Java static method.

You then follow this with ".". But "." is not a valid operator in XPath. If you want to apply one XPath function `F()` to the result of another function `G()`, you can't use the Java syntax `F().G()`, you have to use the XPath syntax `G(F())`. And that means you'll need to use the fully-qualified function name corresponding to minusDays().

Since you're in Java, you could switch to Saxon, which supports all the date-and-time functions built in to XSLT 2.0, so all this calling out to Java for simple date/time arithmetic becomes unnecessary.