# Date library for parsing human readable arithmetic calculations

Tags: java, java-time

I am writing a QA test automation program where people are going to input human readable duration strings with arithmetic operations with values like `now - 5d`, `yesterday`, `now + 8 days`, and I need parse them into java 8 `LocalDateTime` instances.

So simply stated, I need a utility like this:

`LocalDateTime nowMinus5Days = DurationUtil.parseHumanReadableDuration("now - 5d")`

How can I code this in Java? Or is there some library that already exists that I should use instead of trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Do you mean a fixed data set as input or free text?

Comment: fixed set of input is fine.

Comment: I think your Question is too broad. But yes, the java.time api has methods to add days, hours, minutes and a now(). I think you'll have to add some more details for anyone to be able to provide with an actual answer though.

Comment: there i added some detail. did that help?

Comment: It did :) I didn't understand that you wanted to parse text. No, as far as I'm aware, the standard java SE does not provide with a parser for this.

Comment: yeah that's the feeling i'm getting. but there's gotta be some sort of library that does it.

Comment: Hi I would like this re-opened. I should have asked "how to code this in java" versus "what library can i use". but i also will ask, should i use an existing library to prevent reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a starting point. I am guessing that you will want to elaborate it further.

```
private static Pattern relativeTimePattern
        = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s*(?:([+-])\\s*(\\w+))?");
private static Map<String, Supplier<LocalDateTime>> bases
        = Map.of("now", () -> LocalDateTime.now(),
                "yesterday", () -> LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).atStartOfDay()); 

public static LocalDateTime parseRelativeTime(String timeString) {
    Matcher m = relativeTimePattern.matcher(timeString);
    if (m.matches()) {
        String baseString = m.group(1);
        LocalDateTime result = bases.get(baseString).get();
        String signString = m.group(2);
        if (signString != null) {
            boolean subtract = signString.equals("-");
            String diffString = m.group(3);
            TemporalAmount diff;
            try {
                diff = Period.parse("P" + diffString);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
                // try a Duration instead
                diff = Duration.parse("PT" + diffString);
            }
            if (subtract) {
                result = result.minus(diff);
            } else {
                result = result.plus(diff);
            }
        }
        return result;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    System.out.println(parseRelativeTime("now - 5d"));
    System.out.println(parseRelativeTime("yesterday"));
    System.out.println(parseRelativeTime("now + 8d"));
```

Output when I ran just now:

> ```
> 2020-03-30T09:49:18.300731
> 2020-04-03T00:00
> 2020-04-12T09:49:18.307784
> ```

As my method stands, it accepts either of `now` and `yesterday` in lower case optionally followed by a sign (`+` or `-`) and *either* a period of years-months-weeks-days *or* a duration of hours-minutes-seconds. Each of the latter must use one letter abbreviations for the time units (y, m, w, d, h, m, s; when the ambiguous m comes alone, it is taken as months). No spaces are allowed inside the period or duration.

Thinkable further developments include:

- Add more words: `today`, `tomorrow`; consider allowing upper case and mixed case.
- Allow units in full and with space, for example `8 days`. A further regex will convert this to `8d` before the final parsing into a `Period`.
- Disallow the ambiguous `2m` forcing the user to specify for example `2m0d` (2 months 0 days) or `2m0s` (2 minutes 0 seconds). Or force uppercase `M` for months and lowercase `m` for minutes.
- The complicated part: provide useful error messages for strings that cannot be parsed.

Comment: I had something similar I was doing, but I like what you have here better so I am swapping it out. It appears to be working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is pretty much impossible (or at least hard) to cover conversion of every possible String input to a valid date. It could even need some intelligent Natural Language Processing.

I would suggest using a set of fields exposed for input and [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion) them to a desired object. If there is an end user, you can have a user select whether they want to add or subtract date and then present a Text Input where they can enter the number of days. You can handle inputs like "Yesterday" and "Tomorrow" as special inputs.

Java's Date Package is pretty useful and has [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882926/how-to-subtract-x-day-from-a-date-object-in-java) for adding and subtracting a given number of days.