# Adding days to a date in Java

Tags: java, date

How do I add x days to a date in Java?

For example, my date is `01/01/2012`, using `dd/mm/yyyy` as the format.

Adding 5 days, the output should be `06/01/2012`.

Comment: There are more duplicates for this general question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623610/subtracting-days-in-a-calendar-object    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java

Comment: Search for Joda-Time DateTime plusDays for many examples.

Comment: Given you’re using the effectively deprecated `Date` class, the *simplest* (not the best) way is: `returnDate = new Date(borrowDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(14));`

Comment: use DateUtils.addDays(date,3); from org.apache.commons.lang.time library.

Answer (score 122):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date()); // Using today's date
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 5); // Adding 5 days
String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: why setTime to new Date(),  however Calendar.getInstance().getTime() yields the same ?

Answer (score 60):

## java.time

With the Java 8 [Date and Time API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) you can use the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate.now().plusDays(nrOfDays)
```

See the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Correct answer. I would also suggest passing a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to the [`now`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) method rather than relying implicitly on the JVM’s [current default time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--). That default can change at any moment *during runtime*! Better to specify the desired/expected time zone.

Answer (score 25):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
```

You can also subtract days like this: `Calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);`

Answer (score 23):

Here is some simple code that prints the date five days from now:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
```

Example output:

```
16/12/2021
```

See also: [Calendar#add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int))

Answer (score 17):

If you're using [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (and there are lots of good reasons to - a simple, intuitive API and thread safety) then you can do this trivially:

```
new LocalDate().plusDays(5);
```

to add 5 days to today's date, for example.

EDIT: My *current* advice would be to now use the [Java 8 date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)

Comment: How can I get date before 10 days from current date using joda in yyyy-mm-dd format

Comment: Check out the Joda specific DateTimeFormatters

Comment: @Matthias why would you say use Java 8 date/time over Joda now?

Comment: I think the date/time APIs introduced in Java 8 address most (all?) of the definiciences resulting in the original need for Joda....

Answer (score 14):

Simple, without any other API:

To add 8 days to the current day:

```
Date today = new Date();
long ltime = today.getTime()+8*24*60*60*1000;
Date today8 = new Date(ltime);
```

Comment: This code does not account for the fact that days are not always 24-hours long. Technically, this is adding 192 hours rather than 8 days. May be correct depending on what the situation defines as "days".

Comment: 'public static Date addRemoveDays(Date d, int days) {
        long ltime=d.getTime()+days*24*60*60*1000;
        return new Date(ltime);
    } ... Date danes = new Date(); //28.4.2016
Date tooOld = MyUtil.addRemoveDays(danes, -80); //18.5.2016 ERROR???'

Comment: Problem with using code like this is that you can easily overflow int and then go negative:

    90 days * 24*60*60*1000 = (int) -813934592

This takes you _backwards_.

Comment: Not a way to implement like this, i have used this code when i add 29 + 7 it went for 36 where as in date no more than 31 days......