# Returns a Date value that is num days after current Date JAVA

Tags: java, date, date-arithmetic

I have a given task but don't really understand what to perform in this function. Here is the given code:

```
// Returns a Date value that is num days after current Date
public Date daysAfter(int num) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Also add what have you tried and is not working, then seek for help :)

Comment: As the comment already says, it should create and return a `Date` that is `num` days after the current date.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087419/adding-days-to-a-date-in-java

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Comment: `Date` was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach, IMHO, would be to use a Calendar object:

```
public static Date daysAfter(int num) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, num);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you also tell me about implementation of daysBefore() function?

Comment: @JustGamingJG just multiply `num` by `-1`.

Comment: I beg to differ. Compare to [the answer by Raheela Aslam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53257014/5772882). That answer is easier. And clearer to read and more modern. The `Calendar` class has design issues and is long outdated.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can get date plus your provided day as below:

```
public static LocalDate getDateAfter(Integer days) {
    return LocalDate.now().plusDays(days);
}
```