# how to calculate days to get end date in android?

Tags: android, date, calendar

I'm creating an application where I have calculated the start date and end date but I'm getting the output of days.

For example my start date is 2019-05-16 and I write 3 days of leave so it should give me the output for the end date 2019-05-19

Here is my source code:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "d/M/yyyy";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//Here i can use Start date as a 01/01/2018 and End Date is 01/01/2019
System.out.println ("Days: " + getDaysBetweenDates("01/02/2018","01    /01/2019"));
}
public static long getDaysBetweenDates(String start, String end) {
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT,      Locale.ENGLISH);
   Date startDate, endDate;
   long numberOfDays = 0;
    try {
    startDate = dateFormat.parse(start);
    endDate = dateFormat.parse(end);
    numberOfDays = getUnitBetweenDates(startDate, endDate, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return numberOfDays;
 }


private static long getUnitBetweenDates(Date startDate, Date endDate,   TimeUnit unit) {
    long timeDiff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    return unit.convert(timeDiff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
 }
```

But what if I want to calculate the no of days and get the end date result.

[image]  Here I'm getting some errors when I add button.

Comment: Please confirm, Do you want difference of days (from start and end)

Comment: I want to calculate the days and to get end date result

Comment: write your example in question , what you are passing and what is your expected result

Comment: I wrote the example and my expected output @NikunjParadva

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I increment a date by one day in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428918/how-can-i-increment-a-date-by-one-day-in-java)

Comment: Also duplicate of [Adding days to a date in Java [duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087419/adding-days-to-a-date-in-java) and other questions. Please search.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with and has much better support for your task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function for your expected result, in this function you need to pass Start Date and number of days you want to add. and you will get your result

**For Date object**

```
String outputDate = addDays(new Date(),5); //for current date

 public static String addDays(Date startDate,int numberOfDays) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(startDate);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,numberOfDays);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",  Locale.ENGLISH);
    String resultDate=dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
    return resultDate;
}
```

**For String Date**

```
String outputDate = addDays("01/02/2018",5);


public static String addDays(String startDate,int numberOfDays) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",  Locale.ENGLISH);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(startDate));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,numberOfDays);
    String resultDate=dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
    return resultDate;
}
```

Comment: And what about system.out.println which is there in my code

Comment: One more thing let's say if I don't want system.out.println and I want see the result in edit text box so how should I do that.

Comment: I've not added any button to calculate so how do I see the result when I select start date dialog picker.

Comment: do this code on that, or print `outputDate` in LogCat

Comment: It's giving me some errors when I put this code in Button onclickListener.

Comment: Ok I'll put a screen shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193454/discussion-between-huzaifa-yusuf-and-nikunj-paradva).

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);

    int NUMBER_OF_DAY_TO_ADD = 3;

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, NUMBER_OF_DAY_TO_ADD);

    String nextDate = String.valueOf( DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
    System.out.println("Next date will:-> " + nextDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "d/M/yyyy";    

    //Date startDate = new Date(DATE_FORMAT.format(sourceDate));

    // convert date to calendar
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(startDate);

    // manipulate date
    //c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
    //c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);    //add here the number of days 
    //c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    //c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    //c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

    // convert calendar to date
    Date targetDate = c.getTime();

    System.out.println(DATE_FORMAT.format(targetDate));
```